# How to generate a function to download csv files from a dynamic url in R

Tags: r, loops, csv

I am generating a function to download a bunch of CSV database from a "click and download" webpage. It was working wonderful:

```
mydownloadBCA <- function(start_date, end_date) {
  start_date <- as.Date(start_date)
  end_date <- as.Date(end_date)
  dates <- as.Date("1970-01-01") + (start_date : end_date)
  for(i in 1:length(dates)){
    string_date <- as.character(dates[i])
    myfile <- paste0("./BCA/BCA", string_date, ".csv")
    myurl <- paste("https://www.cenace.gob.mx/DocsMEM/OpeMdo/CantidAsig/MDA/ImportacionExportacion/Resultados_ImpExp%20BCA%20MDA%20Dia%20", string_date, "%20v2017%2003%2022_09%2033%2019.csv", sep = "")
    download.file(url = myurl, destfile = myfile, quiet = TRUE)
  }
  }
```

For a first "chunk" the url only varies given a date:

[2016-01-29] https://www.cenace.gob.mx/DocsMEM/OpeMdo/CantidAsig/MDA/ImportacionExportacion/Resultados_ImpExp%20SIN%20MDA%20Dia%20**2016-01-29**%20v2017%2003%2022_10%2033%2019.csv

[2016-10-31]
https://www.cenace.gob.mx/DocsMEM/OpeMdo/CantidAsig/MDA/ImportacionExportacion/Resultados_ImpExp%20SIN%20MDA%20Dia%20**2016-10-31**%20v2017%2003%2022_10%2033%2019.csv

Afterwards the webpage has been updated on a daily basis generating a changing url without a pattern.

After 2017-03-30 the url not only changed in an as.Date basis but in a numerical non-logical way. The problem is the last part **"%XXXX%XXXX_XX%XXXX%XXXX.csv"**

for example:

```
<<url>> = https://www.cenace.gob.mx/DocsMEM/OpeMdo/CantidAsig/MDA/ImportacionExportacion/Resultados_ImpExp%20BCA%20MDA

2017-03-30  <<url>>%20Dia%202017-03-30%20v2017%2003%2029_13%2029%2051.csv
2017-04-01  <<url>>%20Dia%202017-04-01%20v2017%2003%2031_13%2044%2042.csv
2017-04-02  <<url>>%20Dia%202017-04-02%20v2017%2004%2001_12%2057%2041.csv
##  Problems here                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I tried to account for it with a loop but so far it has not been working:

```
mydownloadSIN <- function(start_date, end_date) {
  start_date <- as.Date(start_date)
  end_date <- as.Date(end_date)
  dates <- as.Date("1970-01-01") + (start_date : end_date)
  f <- factor(0:9)
  number <- as.numeric(f)
  for(i in 1:length(dates)){
    for(j in 0:length(number)){
    string_date <- as.character(dates[i])
    X <- as.character(number[j])
    myfile <- paste0("./SIN/SIN", string_date, ".csv")
    myurl <- paste("https://www.cenace.gob.mx/DocsMEM/OpeMdo/CantidAsig/MDA/ImportacionExportacion/Resultados_ImpExp%20SIN%20MDA%20Dia%20",string_date,"%20v2017%",X,X,X,X,"%",X,X,X,X,"_",X,X,"%",X,X,X,X,"%",X,X,X,X,".csv", sep = "")
    download.file(url = myurl, destfile = myfile, quiet = TRUE)
    }
  }
  }
```

When trying using the function I get the following error:

> Error in download.file(url = myurl, destfile = myfile, quiet = TRUE) :
>   cannot open URL
>   'https://www.cenace.gob.mx/DocsMEM/OpeMdo/CantidAsig/MDA/ImportacionExportacion/Resultados_ImpExp%20SIN%20MDA%20Dia%202017-03-24%20v2017%%_%%.csv'
>   In addition: Warning message: In download.file(url = myurl, destfile =
>   myfile, quiet = TRUE) :   cannot open URL
>   'https://www.cenace.gob.mx/DocsMEM/OpeMdo/CantidAsig/MDA/ImportacionExportacion/Resultados_ImpExp%20SIN%20MDA%20Dia%202017-03-24%20v2017%%_%%.csv':
>   HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'

This is the "general" webpage where the user select the years they need and then click on the CSV archive:
[https://www.cenace.gob.mx/SIM/VISTA/REPORTES/H_RepCantAsignadas.aspx?N=135&opc=divCssCantAsig&site=Cantidades%20asignadas/MDA/De%20Importación%20y%20Exportación&tipoArch=C&tipoUni=BCN&tipo=De%20Importación%20y%20Exportación&nombrenodop=MDA](https://www.cenace.gob.mx/SIM/VISTA/REPORTES/H_RepCantAsignadas.aspx?N=135&opc=divCssCantAsig&site=Cantidades%20asignadas/MDA/De%20Importaci%C3%B3n%20y%20Exportaci%C3%B3n&tipoArch=C&tipoUni=BCN&tipo=De%20Importaci%C3%B3n%20y%20Exportaci%C3%B3n&nombrenodop=MDA)

Is there a way I can account for this change in the url for my function?

Thanks

Comment: Just a minor note: I think you mean `CSV` (comma-separated values) not `CVS`.

Comment: It would help a lot if you would isolate the relevant part of the URL and explain what you understand about the pattern when it is consistent (before 2017-03-30?) and then show examples of how it changes after. Also, if there is a page with links to all of the files, that would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry Gregor, I edited already as it properly should be "CSV"

The webpage is this one. After selecting the years you want to download, the csv files appear https://www.cenace.gob.mx/SIM/VISTA/REPORTES/H_RepCantAsignadas.aspx?N=135&opc=divCssCantAsig&site=Cantidades%20asignadas/MDA/De%20Importaci%C3%B3n%20y%20Exportaci%C3%B3n&tipoArch=C&tipoUni=BCN&tipo=De%20Importaci%C3%B3n%20y%20Exportaci%C3%B3n&nombrenodop=MDA

Comment: From 2016-01-29

https://www.cenace.gob.mx/DocsMEM/OpeMdo/CantidAsig/MDA/ImportacionExportacion/Resultados_ImpExp%20SIN%20MDA%20Dia%202016-01-29%20v2017%2003%2022_10%2033%2019.csv 

To 2016-09-30

https://www.cenace.gob.mx/DocsMEM/OpeMdo/CantidAsig/MDA/ImportacionExportacion/Resultados_ImpExp%20BCA%20MDA%20Dia%202016-09-30%20v2017%2003%2022_09%2033%2019.csv

Essentially they change because the first months they were uploaded as a "chunk" the same day, afterward they were uploaded on a daily basis